# The value in the textbox will not pass to microsoft access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and programming in VB.  I am trying to pass a string from a textbox to a Microsoft Office 365 Access Database.
My code:

```
Using cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=C:\...\...\...\...accdb;")

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Client_Information WHERE @FirstName", cn)

        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@First Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = FirstNameTextBox.Text
            '.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = LastNameTextBox.Text
        End With

        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cn.Close()
    End Using
```

It seems to work but no value is posted to Access.  This is a form after a log-in form that does work.  When I use an INSERT INTO command before the SELECT statement it throws and exception.

OleDbException was unhandled

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause in your query above is improperly formatted. Also, please post the code for the `INSERT` and the resulting error.

Comment: The INSERT INTO would go right before SELECT.

Comment: If you would post the code for the `INSERT` and the resulting error, you might get a useful answer.

Comment: I added it to the main comment.